# How to remove the password from each line? in the format of example:pass

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

How can I remove the passwords from a text file that contains email:password?

For example I have :

```
willibaldkahr@a1.net:1241_1130 
keyskyer@wo.com.cn:k8795530
nakamura@a1.net:nakamura
t.fessl@a1.net:legeres18
jsburns@cox.net:shorty01
pixel@minikomp.com:Symbian3G
decky21@netvigator.com:decky21
```

I want to get the following result :

```
 willibaldkahr@a1.net
 keyskyer@wo.com.cn
 nakamura@a1.net
 t.fessl@a1.net
 jsburns@cox.net
 pixel@minikomp.com
 decky21@netvigator.com
```

Answer (score 3):

#### How can I remove the passwords?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*):.*`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]
**Before**:

```
willibaldkahr@a1.net:1241_1130 
keyskyer@wo.com.cn:k8795530
nakamura@a1.net:nakamura
t.fessl@a1.net:legeres18
jsburns@cox.net:shorty01
pixel@minikomp.com:Symbian3G
decky21@netvigator.com:decky21
```

**After**:

```
willibaldkahr@a1.net
keyskyer@wo.com.cn
nakamura@a1.net
t.fessl@a1.net
jsburns@cox.net
pixel@minikomp.com
decky21@netvigator.com
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: thank you it did work perfectly

Comment: @TeSam You're welcome, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button)

Answer (score 1):

1. CTRL + H -> will open replace window
2. Type **:.*** in 'Find what' field.
3. Select 'Regular expression' in 'Search Mode'.
4. Click 'Replace All' buton.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFox6.png)